# How can I differentiate between records in a has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paperclip

I have a table of venues, venuetypes and just added a table of venuetype_icons.

Currently a venue belongs to a venuetype and a venuetype has many venues. Each venue is displayed with an icon depicting its venuetype.

The venues can be either free or premium and I would like for each venuetype to have 2 icons, one for a free venue and one for a premium venue.

I have set up venuetypes to have many venuetype_icons. The venuetype_icon records have a name field and the paperclip file fields.

I'd like to set my view up as such:

```
<% if venue.plan == 'premium' %>
  display the premium venuetype_icon
<% else %>
  display the regular free icon
<% end %>
```

But how can I differentiate between the free and premium icons if there stored in the same table? Would it be possible to add in a drop down when creating new icons to mark them as free or premium? and if so how would that work in the view?

I hope this makes sense, please ask for any clarification if needed.

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you know that for each VenueType, there's only going to be one icon per plan, and the amount of plans is going to be pretty limited and hardcoded, I would reverse the relation from VenueType to VenueTypeIcons:

```
class VenueType
  belongs_to :free_icon, :class_name => "VenueTypeIcon", :foreign_key => "venue_type_icon_free_id"
  belongs_to :premium_icon, :class_name => "VenueTypeIcon", :foreign_key => "venue_type_icon_premium_id"
end
```